# get maximum as an array in case of more than one with same maximum value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, max

Ruby has `Enumerable#max` and `Enumerable#max_by` and I am using `max_by` in the following way.

```
array = [
           {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}, 
           {:a => 3, :b => 2, :c => 4}, 
           {:a => 3, :b => 1, :c => 4}
        ]
max_item = array.max_by { |item| item[:b] }
=> {:b=>2, :c=>3, :a=>1}
```

So, it will return a single maximum (I think first), even though there are 2 items with same maximum value. I want to implement a function which gives both the items in such cases. Is there some other variant of `max_by` or do I need to write from scratch for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
array = [
           {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}, 
           {:a => 3, :b => 2, :c => 4}, 
           {:a => 3, :b => 1, :c => 4}
        ]

array.group_by{|el| el[:b]}.max.last 
#=>[{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}, {:a=>3, :b=>2, :c=>4}]
```

`group_by` works a little too hard, but it does deliver.

Comment: Didn't know about `group_by`; neat.

Comment: I knew about `group_by` but was not able to think through this logic..I had to read the post twice to get the logic..splendid!!

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't such a method. However, the following should do (I've added it to `Array` simply because I was working in `irb` - you can monkey-patch it wherever makes most sense)

```
class Array
  def maxes_by &block
    max_condition = block.call(max_by(&block))
    select {|it| block.call(it) == max_condition}
  end
end

array = [
           {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}, 
           {:a => 3, :b => 2, :c => 4}, 
           {:a => 3, :b => 1, :c => 4}
        ]
array.maxes_by{|it| it[:b]}
# => [{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}, {:a=>3, :b=>2, :c=>4}]
```

Comment: You are calling `block` (which is potentially expensive operation) twice for each element +1, `group_by` is definitely better solution.